# Angular Universal view page source not showing API data

Tags: angular, view, universal

I have an Angular 6 application which is working fine on both local development environment as well as on production machine. The data is fed by an API to the application. Application is showing the data just fine by using observable, resolve and promise techniques.

I have made a Universal version of the application (Server Side Rendering or SSR) for SEO purposes which also works fine.

I just have one issue;

**When I post my application to production, it displays the contents that are coming from the API just fine, however when I view the "Page Source" on the browser, I'm not able to see the contents that were rendered on the page.**

Please note that I have the data coming through "Route Resolve" and it is not the case of async/await issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for a late response since this was an issue from last year and because I figured out what the issue was, I never looked at this issue again. I try to explain here as much as I can.

The data was coming through an AWS API Gateway which was connected to the app via credentials and keys. The data was showing just fine on the page but not when I was looking at the page source. I thought that there is a problem with the API, but after spending days figuring out, I found out that the data is just getting received fine from the API.

I just used "inspect" on the page on Chrome (right click and inspect) and looked at "console" tab and realized a bunch of methods in the app throwing errors. When I investigated the errors I found out there are bunch of data type mismatches associated with the data types I was getting from the API.

As a result, the issue was with the app not the API. A silly issue like this took me almost a week to fix. I hope this would shed some light for you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I'm having the same issue.  However in my case some pages are rendering fine - the source is populated correctly, and other pages aren't showing anything in source at all.

Comment: Can you please explain how you fix this issue?

Comment: I just re-typed the answer above. Sorry for a late response.

Comment: @rezafard there are some pages which has no data types mismatch and still those pages are not showing API data in source file, however the localhost prod build is independent of the console data type mismatch error? Is is sth same that you were also facing?

Comment: @MrAJ, I didn't have any other issue thereafter. In your prod version, have you taken a look at your browser console to find out what type of error you get?

Comment: @rezafard yes at one case I was using the title and meta description service which was not defined which worked in most pages, however just one page which has the title service using removing of htmlchars was updating the title however it is not showing in the source page. 90% issues are solved. Thanks upvoting the ans.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I tested a lot of solutions, and the solution was very simple. When hitting the API, I was using the path “/api”, I changed it to an absolute path, e.g., “https://example.com/api” or “http://localhost/api” and that solved the problem. The data fetched from the API is displayed in the browser's "view source" and is accessible to search engine bots.