# Angular SSR is not displaying data from API in page source on browser for server deployed SSR but working on local prod build

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I have an angular 7 application and have made a universal version of the application (SSR for SEO purpose).

The application runs all smooth like before, all data from API are displayed perfectly in local mode as well as in server.

The issue is however when I view the "Page Source" on the browser the API data is not visible in browser if fetched from server.

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run nthexam:server:production",
  },
```

The command `npm run build:ssr:stage && npm run serve:ssr` build the SSR application and it works perfectly fine in local machine.

**ISSUE**

The page source on the browser do not show API data if SSR is deployed in server (ubuntu)
however for static content its works all fine.

In local its works perfectly for static as well as API data, both are visible in page source in localhost.

After some search: 
I am using **cloudflare**, I tried by disabling all the cache, still of no use.

I tried this : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972936/angular-universal-view-page-source-not-showing-api-data/51978030)
But in few pages where I don't have any console error even then it don't show the data in page source, and local it works perfectly fine irrespective of the stated error.

Answer (score -1):

The page source shows the static files requested from the server. Anything that happens on the client side, like API calls to your server, doesn't affect the source. You can see API data in the network tab in the xhr request or in the DOM under the elements tab if the data was parsed into the DOM.

Comment: In local setup all API data is showing in page source as well , else SSR is of no use.

Comment: Then I guess I'm confused. Can you add a bit of code from source showing with the data and without the data?

Comment: Think of a condition where you have to list all post from API, 
On local do:  `npm run build:ssr:stage && npm run serve:ssr` and then check the page source it shows all posts in page source on browser.

And doing the same in server : `npm run build:ssr:stage && npm run serve:ssr`  just show the static content not the API data in page source on browser,  

for eg: this is page source 
`<header> //static data </header> <app-main>
<h3>Show all post </h3> 
<div> // in local it shows all post here 
// in server this block is empty
</div>
</app-main><footer></footer>`

Comment: But the posts render on the page in both situations?

Comment: yes all posts shows fine in UI just in page source it's the difference.

Comment: I've been reading up on this and it seems at first glance that this renders all pages on the server side, but it actually just renders 1 page and then loads the SPA on the browser anyways. So if you already have it cached on your browser (I know you cleared the server cache, but did you clear the browser cache?) then the SPA can already take over. If you enter a new url the ssr is requested again, but if you follow links it's all client side.

Comment: Yes you are right, that I tried to load the new page (new url) refreshed, it should display that page data. However the behaviour is same as before.

Comment: You said that you made a Universal *version*; is the client-side version still on your server in the same production folder? Maybe locally you removed it but on the server your original version is superceding the Universal version?